# Sorting a linear data structure in place

Tags: c++, list, iterator

How do I convert this function into a function that sorts the list `a` in place? I currently have the following:

```
template<typename Iterator>
void LISTsort(Iterator curr, Iterator stop)
{
    //how to sort in place
}
```

I failed to wrap around my head about how to "put" the values back to the `list a`. I know that I can use a while loop and replace each individual `*curr` and incrementing the iterator.  Is there any way to accomplish this without using any loops?.

Comment: what's wrong with loops?

Comment: P.S. this is not sorting in-place.

Comment: how about calling [`std::list::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::list` has a member function for sorting. It's called `sort`.

> Is there any way to accomplish this without using any loops?.

Only way to sort without using loops (recursive or iterative) is to limit the size of the input to a constant.

Comment: my bad I didn't know list have a sort function

Comment: @JayEstrera sorry for picking on it, but your mistake was not that you didnt know it exists, the problem was that you didnt look at documentation of `std::list` to find it (I didn't know it as well, but I had to look it up)